# how to measure the processor speed in GHz in JAVA

Tags: java, clock

i was able to measure the execution time of program but dont know how to calculate the processor speed. This is required for calculating the clock cycles.

```
noofclockcycles = time * processorspeed * pow(10,9) / pow(10,3);
```

Comment: i dont think you can, since clock does not represent execution speed - its not linear

Comment: You can use JNI to invoke native code that get hardware infomation for you.

Comment: XY problem, probably. What do you want to do? And remember that there is the JIT to account for.

Answer (score 0):

What you call processor "speed" (clock rate) has no direct relationship to processing capacity, and much less with what part of that processing capacity your program will be assigned by the OS.  It's like trying to find out the RPM of a motor only by its current power output or maximum torque.

You can do an extremely rough approximation by `clockRate_B = ( execTime_A * clockRate_A ) / execTime_B`, where `( execTime_A * clockRate_A )` was obtained from a  typical machine (or set of typical machines).  However, this doesn't account for CPU architecture differences that can make your test run several times faster or slower at exactly the same clock rate.

Best thing you can do is to `exec` OS utilities (like `cpuinfo` in Linux and `wmic` in Windows) to obtain this information.